# Store multiple UILocalNotification in UserInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

this is how i setting my local notification, all work well.

```
        NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit |NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[_datePicker date]];
        NSLog(@"%@",[_datePicker date]);
        NSDate *fireDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components];
        NSLog(@"Fire date : %@",fireDate);

        // check if the time is already passed
        if ([fireDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending)
        {
            // if it does add 1 day
            components.day = components.day+1;
            fireDate = [gregorianCalendar dateFromComponents:components];
        }
        NSLog(@"Fire date : %@",fireDate);


        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

            NSDate *scheduleDate = [fireDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(i * 24.0f * 3600.0f)];
            NSDateComponents *componentsForEachDay = [gregorianCalendar components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:scheduleDate];
            if (componentsForEachDay.weekday != 7) { // To skip Saturday

                localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
                localNotification.fireDate = fireDate;
                localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
                localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
                localNotification.alertBody = @"test";
                localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
                localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

                    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bracletNotif%i",i]];
localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

i always get only the last object in userInfo.. how can i store all the scheduleLocalNotification in the userInfo for later cancel?
how does its work? before every scheduleLocalNotification i need so save an object and key? or can i save them all at one?
because i already tried to do that, i got all the userInfo objects but could not delete them :/

SOS please.

Comment: Just to let you know you have `localNotification.repeatInterval` twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to cancel all `braclet` notifications instead of giving them all a different key/value you could do this instead:

```
localNotification.userInfo = @{@"category": @"bracelet"};
```

To cancel:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UILocalNotification *notification, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *userInfo;
    if((userInfo = [notification userInfo])){
        NSString *categoryValue;
        if((categoryValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"category"]) && [categoryValue isEqualToString:@"bracelet"]){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification: notification];
        }
    }
}];
```

What we are doing here is grouping all notifications into the `category`: `bracelet`. I have chosen the key `category` due to future changes in the sdk. We could schedule more notifications e.g. `category`: `neckless`

Then when required we loop through all the `UILocalNotifications` and scan for the `category` key in the notifications `userInfo`, in the example above if the keys value equals `bracelet`, then we cancel the notification.

```
if((categoryValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"category"]) && [categoryValue isEqualToString:@"bracelet"]){
```

This line of code is checking whether a key of `category` exists (i.e. not `nil`) whilst assigning it to the variable `categoryValue` then the if statement is immediately checking if the `categoryValue` is equal to `bracelet`

It could have been rewritten as:

```
NSString *categoryValue = [userInfo objectForKey:@"category"];
if(categoryValue && [categoryValue isEqualToString:@"bracelet"]){
```

Comment: works well, thank you! but could you explain what we did here?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! i have 1 more Q.. how does the userInfo work? every time we give it '@{@"category": @"bracelet"};' its overrides the previous one? or he put all the bracelet notif in the same category?  Thanks again, really appreciate it.

Comment: `userInfo` is an `NSDictionary` stored on the `UILocalNotification` object. When you `alloc init` you are creating a new object, we assign the `category` key in the objects `userInfo`. It is not being overridden as `alloc init` is resetting the `localNotification` variable.

Comment: got it.. i didnt alloc init the userInfo, thats the reason i got only the last object. thank you very much my friend!